# Column of buttons in a table in JSP using displaytag and Struts 1.3

Tags: java, jsp, dispatcher, struts-1, displaytag

I need to display the table containing a list of users (`id`, `name`, etc.) and place the buttons to delete specified user in the last column. Something like this:

```
############################
| ID | name | ... | button |   
| ID | name | ... | button |
############################
```

I've wrote code like this:

```xml
<form action="/Struts/DeleteUser.do" name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post">
    <display:table name="sessionScope.AllUsersForm.usersList">
       <display:column property="id" title="ID" />
       <display:column property="name" title="Name" />
       ...........
       <display:column title="Delete">
            <input type="submit" value="Delete user" />
       </display:column>
    </display:table>
<form>
```

So how can I identify pressed button in my Action class? I've already tried to place a hidden field into section with button and change it's value but nothing happened.

**UPDATED:**

I've already solved problem. I've used this:

```xml
<display:table name="sessionScope.AllUsersForm.usersList" 
  <%-- This ==> --%> id="item" <%-- <=== --%> >     
  ........
  <input type="submit"  value="Delete user" 
     onclick="document.getElementById('pressedButton').value = ${item.id}"/>
```

And created hidden field:

```xml
<input type="hidden" name="pressedButton" id="pressedButton" />
```

Comment: Simpler solution: do not use `form` and multiple `submit` buttons, use links in each row, e.g. `<a href="/Struts/DeleteUser.do?pressedButton=${item.id}">Delete user</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could easy do it by giving a name to the button, for example

```
<input name="action" type="submit" value="Delete user" />
```

now in the bean that in, your case form bean associated to the action, you should create a property

```
private String action;
public void setAction(String action){
  this.action = action;
}
public String getAction(){
  return action;
}
```

Struts 1 used commons beanutils to populate form bean. When you submit the form the field values are populated via setters. The button field is not exception from the rules. So, its value will also be set to the `action` property. Then you could check it via

```
if (action != null && action.equals("Delete user")){
  System.out.println("Button is: "+action);
}
```

The most natural Struts 1 way to identify and execute button events is to dispatch the message key value along with button. For example

```
<html:submit><bean:message key="button.delete"/></html:submit>
```

The `"button.delete"` is a message resource key, should be in `MessageResource.properties` file

```
button.delete = Delete user
```

The action should implement `LookupDispatchAction` and override

```
@Override
public Map getKeyMethodMap() {
  Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  map.put("button.delete", "delete");
  return map;
}
```

then when action is executed it will dispatch to the method specified in the `map`. In this example method `delete`.

Comment: But all my buttons have the same names and actions. And all of them are created dynamically depending on size of the list.

Comment: You have to dispatch the action how is explained in this answer. If you want to add additional parameters then you should pass them either in the url or as hidden fields.